# what's wrong with this wcf rest implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, rest, wcf

I have a wcf rest service method.  The OperationContract looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "?maps/reporttypes/{reportType}/reportperiods/{reportPeriod}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Map GetData(int reportType, int reportPeriod);
```

I can test this successfully with the WCF Test Client so I know the underlying method works. However, I'm having problems getting the data with the $.ajax() method:

```
$.ajax({    
    url: 'http://localhost:52672/Service1.svc?maps/reporttypes/1/reportperiods/1',
    success:function(data){
       //bind data here
    },
    error:function(error){
    }
});
```

The ajax method above returns success but the data value is just the html for the page that gets displayed if you select "View in Browser" for the service.  Any idea what I might be missing in this implementation?

Comment: I think there's a typo in the url. Instead of a question mark, there should be a slash: http://localhost:8080/service1.svc/reports/reportypes...

Comment: Additionally, please note that there's another typo in the UriTemplate. One segment is *reportypes* instead of *reporttypes*. But since it's identically misspelled in both places it shouldn't matter too much ;)

Comment: I updated the code in my dev environment as well as the code in my original post.  The url returns success but only returns the html for the default service view.  What am I missing here?

Comment: are both the things running on the same port? can you see the html if some error is mentioned.?

Comment: they are running on different ports.  the main website is running on localhost:8080 whereas the service is running on localhost:52672.  There is no error in the html.  The html simply reflects a generic html page for the service:  https://jsbin.com/juwizokoje/edit?html,output

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to copy/paste the url into the address bar and then submit?  Shouldn't this return the json from the method and display it in the browser?

Comment: As I mentioned: The Question mark is the problem.

Comment: khlr - will you please post what the url should look like in the ajax and what the uri should look like in the wcf definition?

Comment: I also updated my WebGet to specify ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json but this doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Here's a zip file of the very basic solution:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ynoywrhky6qi98/StackOverflow-20161013.zip?dl=0

Here's the test page:

https://jsbin.com/ficakoraku/edit?html,output

Please let me know if you can get this example to return json to the svc call on the page

Comment: web.config needed to be updated for rest.  this article provides a good reference: 

http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2013/09/simple-steps-for-restful-service.html

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out there is a fundamental issue with your configuration.
In order to use a restful WCF-service you need a `webHttpBinding` instead of the `basicHttpBinding` which you were using.

An example of a working config would this `<system.serviceModel>`-node:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="MapService5.Service1">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MapService5.IService1" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Default">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

By having that change done, you're already able to invoke the method directly via your browser:

[image]

The next error reason is the already mentioned question mark which you used incorrectly. You tried to invoke the method like this:

```
http://localhost:52672/Service1.svc?maps/reporttypes/1/reportperiods/1
```

Whereas it has to be invoked like that:

```
http://localhost:52672/Service1.svc/maps/reporttypes/1/reportperiods/1
```

Please notice the **slash** (`/`) right after `Service1.svc`.

If you're using a question mark (`?`) the rest of the string (`?maps/reporttypes/1/reportperiods/1`) will be treated as a *query-string* which is not what you're looking for in your situation. You need a simple `GET` without any query params, which can be achieved by using the latter link above.

The UriTemplate has to be restored to the string you had before. Again the question mark vs. slash issue ;)

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/maps/reporttypes/{reportType}/reportperiods/{reportPeriod}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```